# Three tables - two identical, one with identifiers, MySQL - retrieve rows

Tags: mysql

I know I should probably be using a JOIN of some kind here, but I have run into problems.

The query below does seem to work - but the query takes ages to load. I am sure there must be a cleaner way to do it?

```
SELECT  
    DISTINCT SN.TermID AS id, SN.TermName AS name
FROM 
    wrex_termnames SN, wrex_term_registrations S, wrex_terms_summer_registrations X
WHERE 
    (SN.TermID = S.TermID AND S.TermPupilID = $id)
    OR
    (SN.TermID = X.TermID AND X.TermPupilID = $id)
ORDER BY termName DESC
```

The table structure is as follows:

***wrex_termnames*** - a database with the names of the terms, i.e. 2008/09, 2009/10, 2010/11 which has fields **TermID** and **TermName**

***wrex_term_registrations*** - a database of terms which pupils have registered for, which have fields **TermID** and **TermPupilID**

***wrex_term_summer_registrations*** - a database of special summer terms which pupils have registered for, which also have fields **TermID** and **TermPupilID**

What I want to do is only return the names of the terms from wrex_termnames which have registrations logged against them in either wrex_term_registrations or wrex_terms_summer_registrations for the pupil I am interested in ($id).

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992. Come. Join us.

Comment: Slow queries almost always benefit from an index review. And I don't see how SN.TermID = S.TermID can work since wrex_term_registrations   S does not have termid.

Comment: Apologies P.Salmon, an error in my explanation there, have amended that.